# Как в тегах "audio" поставить preload="none", если они не воспроизведены?

Tags: javascript

Вот мой код, не понимаю, куда добавить

```
var audioNL = document.querySelectorAll('audio');
    var audio = Array.apply(null, audioNL);

    audio.forEach(t => {
        var index = audio.indexOf(t);

        t.addEventListener('play', ()=> {
            audio.forEach(subT => {
                subT !== audio[index] ?
                (subT.pause(), subT.currentTime = 0) :
                subT.play()
            })
        })
        t.addEventListener('ended', ()=> {
            t.currentTime = 0;
            index !== audio.length - 1 ?
                audio[index + 1].play() :
                null
        })
    });
```

Мой сайт, где хочу это сделать https://dragon-music.ru

Когда включаешь больше 6 треков, он зависает. Или может проблема не в этом?

Comment: что в консоли браузера пишет?

Comment: preload=“none”отвечает за состояние элемента аудио до того, как что-то пытаются воспроизвести. Действительно каждый трек грузит проц. Очень плавная загрузка изображений сверху вниз, даже на скорости интернет-подключения 200 кб/с, такое бывает при очень больших размерах фонового изображения в пикселях.

Comment: То есть нужно уменьшить размер фонового изображения?